# Chrome (maybe Safari?) fires "blur" twice on input fields when browser loses focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, dom-events

[Here is an interesting jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/pDYsM/)

In Firefox:

1. Run the fiddle
2. Click in text input
3. Click somewhere else. Should say "1 blurs".
4. Click in the text input again.
5. <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> to another window. Fiddle should now say "2 blurs".

In Chrome, at step 5, it says "3 blurs".  Two separate "blur" events are fired when the whole browser loses focus.  This is of interest because it means that it's not safe to assume, in a "blur" handler, that the element actually had focus just before the event was dispatched; that is, that the loss of focus — the transition from "being in focus" to "not being in focus" — is the reason for the event. When *two* "blur" events are generated, that condition is not satisfied during the handling of the second event, as the element is already not in focus.

So is this just a bug?  Is there a way to tell that a "blur" event is bogus?

Comment: Also happens when you just press Tab to focus the wrench menu, or focus the address bar (basically focusing everything outside the page)... Doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: This is a question for `google-chrome` developers not `Stackoverflow`. (IMO)

Comment: Well @gdoron that will be true if nobody out there knows a way to either detect the redundant blur, or to somehow prevent it. I agree that it seems unlikely for there to be a solution, but there are a lot of smart people here :-)

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen in Safari.

Comment: @pimvdb ah ok thanks a lot for checking for me :-)  I don't have a Windows VM on the machine I'm using now, and I don't have a Mac at all. I should try the Android browser.

Comment: native `addEventListener` works the same way, so this is not a `jQuery` bug. Safari 4 on WinXP generates 1 event.

Comment: Wow I didn't event think of checking that, @kirilloid - thanks ...

Comment: Try it in Opera - there is no blur event on tab switch, or app switch. You can minimize browser, cycle through tabs, but your page focus (and a caret) will stay where they should - inside of the `input` element. IE9 behaves just like WebKit, but i think their behaviour is clearly wrong in this case.

Comment: Its not a bug. Its the proper behavior for javascript.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I think it's somewhat debatable which behavior is appropriate. Just because the window becomes unfocused doesn't mean that the focused element in the document needs to become unfocused. Or is this behavior supposed to be dictated by some specification?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow I believe this specification does mean that the behavior is appropriate, but it may just be my interpretation.

Comment: @Fresheyeball well, that was a quick debate. I think you're right, they've included `defaultView` in the model there.

Comment: @c69 yes also I notice that from my Android browser, there's no "blur" when I switch to another app, and the input element does not effectively lose focus when I leave and return to the browser.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason it is firing twice is because of window.onblur. The window blurring triggers a blur event on all elements in that window as part of the way javascript's capturing/bubbling process. All you need to do is test the event target for being the window.

```
var blurCount = 0;
var isTargetWindow = false;
$(window).blur(function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    isTargetWindow = true;
});
$(window).focus(function(){
    isTargetWindow = false;
});
$('input').blur(function(e) {
    if(!isTargetWindow){         
       $('div').text(++blurCount + ' blurs');
    }
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/pDYsM/4/

Comment: I'm not sure it's really any less complicated, but it does seem to indicate that the behavior is not a bug.

Comment: Maybe its not less complicated, it just seemed that way to me reading it. I am editing my statement to reflect that. Yeah its not a bug, its the way its supposed to work. The other benefit of my method is that its completely cross browser compatible.

Comment: Why are you using a flag and not checking who is the target in the blur event??? it could be a lot more simple answer.

Comment: this may be a weird jQuery thing, but using .blur alone shows the target as 'input' twice. Hooking a separate window blur function is the only way I know to get that as the target. Also also, we need to make sure the flag is reset on window focus, as we cannot reliably do that in input.blur. There may be a better way here to do this than a flag, but I have not gotten it to work.

Comment: Well that sort-of makes sense, but it definitely does not happen that way in Firefox. That makes me wonder whether I can check the event target ...

Comment: @Fresheyeball the thing is, when I check the `event.target` in Chrome, it's the element itself and not the `window` on **both** firings. That is, the "target" property if the event object is the input element itself. If the firing of the handler was due to bubbling or capturing, I would hope that that would not be the case.

Comment: @Pointy now that does sound like a chrome bug, I would report it. However I still believe the behavior to be correct.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Agreed, though the whole "capturing" thing is looking less and less relevant ...

Comment: @Pointy you are completely right, but then again alot of javascript's intended behavior just sucks. Would you consider accepting my answer?

Answer (score 3):

This is confirmed Chrome bug. [See the Chromium Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117307)

The workaround is in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Skip 2nd blur:

```
var secondBlur = false;
this.onblur = function(){
    if(secondBlur)return;
    secondBlur = true;
    //do whatever
}
this.onfocus = function(){
    secondBlur = false;    
    //do whatever
}
```

Comment: This is a very narrow solution. Who's to say that the input should only blur once for the life of the page? What if the user updates the input, tabs away, click back in, then update again and tab.

Comment: As written, this solution is actually both simple and effective. It will work correctly in the situation Ali Cheaito describes.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't what you want to hear, but the only way to do it seems to be to manually track whether the element is focused or not. For example ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pDYsM/2/)):

```
var blurCount = 0;
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onblur = function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    console.log('blur', e);
    if (!(e.target || e.srcElement)['data-focused']) return;
    (e.target || e.srcElement)['data-focused'] = false;
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = (++blurCount + ' blurs');
};
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onfocus = function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    console.log('focus', e);
    (e.target || e.srcElement)['data-focused'] = true;
};
```

Interestingly, I couldn't get this to work in jQuery ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pDYsM/1/)) ... I really don't use jQuery much, maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

```
var blurCount = 0;
$('input').blur(function(e) {
    console.log('blur', e);
    if (!(e.target || e.srcElement)['data-focused']) return;
    (e.target || e.srcElement)['data-focused'] = false;
    $('div').innerHTML = (++blurCount + ' blurs');
});
$('input').focus(function(e) {
    console.log('focus', e);
    (e.target || e.srcElement)['data-focused'] = true;
});
```

---

You could also try comparing the event's target with `document.activeElement`. This example will ignore the alt+tab blur events, and the blur events resulting from clicking on Chrome's... chrome. This could be useful depending on the situation. If the user alt+tabs back into Chrome, it's as if the box never lost focus ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDYsM/3/)).

```
var blurCount = 0;
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onblur = function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    console.log('blur', e, document.activeElement, (e.target || e.srcElement));
    if ((e.target || e.srcElement) == document.activeElement) return;
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = (++blurCount + ' blurs');
};​
​
```

Comment: Yes this is basically what I was falling back to, but it raises the question of whether I should trust the "focus" event too :-)

Comment: @Pointy `timeStamp` of such doubled events would be very close, but I'm afraid, one cannot rely on this.

Comment: @Pointy I bet you could do some kind of CSS `:focus` hack, but that sounds even worse.

Comment: @GGG the pure js method will break in ie8- as they events are window.event instead of being passed into the relevant function.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Yeah, good point. You know it and I know it and the OP knows it, but I should probably add it for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m on Windows 7 and this issue appears to have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same and the above posts make sense as to why. In my case I just wanted to know if *at least* one blur event had occurred. As a result I found that just returning from my blur function solved my issue and prevented the subsequent event from firing.

```
   function handleEditGroup(id) {
        var groupLabelObject = $('#' + id);
        var originalText = groupLabelObject.text();

        groupLabelObject.attr('contenteditable', true)
            .focus().blur(function () {
                $(this).removeAttr('contenteditable');
                $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 60));

                if ($(this).text() != originalText) {
                    alert("Change Found");
                    return; //<--- Added this Return.
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: A `return` at that point in your function would make no difference at all, since the function would naturally return at that point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an oddity of angularjs gives a simpler solution when using ng-blur; the $event object is only defined if you pass it in:

```
ng-blur="onBlur($event)"
```

so (if you aren't using ng-blur on the window) you can check for:

```
$scope.onBlur = function( $event ) {
    if (event != undefined) {
       //this is the blur on the element
    }
}
```