# jQuery blur event fired twice in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I created a simple 'infinite' form with input fields.
Every time an empty input is focused it creates a new one, and on blur of an empty input field, the field is removed.

See [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/EPxkh/)

I use the following code to make it all happen:

```
var $input = $('<div/>').html( $('<input/>').addClass('value') );
$('form').append( $input.clone() );

$('form').on( 'focus', 'input.value', function(e) {

    // Add new input if the focused one is empty
    if(!$.trim(this.value).length) {
        $('form').append( $input.clone() );
    }


}).on( 'blur', 'input.value', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if( !$.trim(this.value).length ) {
        console.log('REMOVING INPUT');
        $this.parent().remove();
    } else {
        $this.attr('name', 'item-'+$this.val());
    }

});
```

The problem is however, that in Chrome the `blur` event is fired twice when I switch to another application (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>). This gives an error, because it is not possible to remove the node, since it's already gone:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

Firefox seems to work fine.

So why is the `blur` event fired twice and how can I prevent that from happening?

**EDIT** - Tried the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649966/chrome-maybe-safari-fires-blur-twice-on-input-fields-when-browser-loses-foc), but no luck. Still get the error message in Chrome, what am I doing wrong?

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EPxkh/3/)

Is there a way to check if the element still exists? Because the second time `blur` fires the node is removed. `$(this).length` still is non-zero though.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649966/chrome-maybe-safari-fires-blur-twice-on-input-fields-when-browser-loses-foc

Comment: yes I knew this looked familiar :-)

Comment: Thanks, stupid me, searched for jQuery :( Trying it now

Comment: Updated question, the solution proposed in the other question doesn't seem to work, or I am doing something horribly wrong here... http://jsfiddle.net/EPxkh/3/

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring because even with the `isTargetWindow` fix, the events are firing in the wrong order - if you look at the javascript console, you'll see that you get both of the "REMOVING INPUT" lines before "window blur". I'm not sure how to fix that, but could be a direction to look in!

Comment: Try to use event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this fiddle is having the behaviour as you need it,
http://jsfiddle.net/EPxkh/8/

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Unfortunately, I still get `NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8` in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Blink, there is a bug report about that on Chromium project's page:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253253