# double actuating onblur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have javascript code, which should be executed once at focus shift. Everything works, but this code is carried out two times for some strange reason, thus I give TWO alert windows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').blur(function() {

        var formData = {
            "username":$('#username').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url:'check.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'jsonData=' + $.toJSON(formData),
            success: function(res) {
                alert(res);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have more than one element with `id="username"` attribute?

Comment: OK, what happens if you replace `alert` with `console.log`? Does the event still fire twice?

Comment: Salman A, yes, it appears twice.

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle with almost your exact code](http://jsfiddle.net/NXSVr/) and the alert happens only once.  Is it possible that your code is running *twice*? If you put **two** event handlers for "blur" you'll get to ajax calls ...

Comment: Hmmm, I see **two** requests to check.php in the Firebug. Why this happens, if I post it just **once**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I moved this code before #username div and everything have worked as it should.

Answer (score 5):

Some browsers (Chrome, maybe Safari) fire a separate "blur" event when the browser *window* loses focus. It seems like a bug to me, and I don't know what can be done about it.

To elaborate: if you've got a "blur" handler on an `<input>`, and it's got focus, and then you click outside the browser window (or ALT-TAB to another application), then Chrome fires *two* "blur" events. Both events will look pretty much the same, so it's hard to tell whether you should pay attention or not.

The best suggestion I have is to toggle some "class" value or something on "focus" and "blur", and ignore a "blur" that doesn't look to be in the proper "I was just focused" state.

[Here's the question I posted on that issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649966/chrome-maybe-safari-fires-blur-twice-on-input-fields-when-browser-loses-foc)

Comment: I had a similar problem but then I totally ignored it (only chrome tho, defiantly not Safari). It's good to know the reason now.

Comment: If I change "blur" event to "onclick" event this problem persists. So, I also have problem in opera and firefox, not only chrome(or safari)