# Bootstrap tooltip onblur firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

[I have been reading through S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282925/double-actuating-onblur-event) and I am seeing that the blur event is getting called twice for many people. I'll be honest, I just don't understand *why*.

**JavaScript:**

```
// call tooltip
initTooltip($element, {'trigger': 'manual', 'placement': 'bottom', 'title': Messages[$element.id + 'Required']});



initTooltip: function($element, options) {
    console.log('--- initTooltip ---'); // this is getting executed 1x
    $('#' + $element.id).tooltip({
        'placement': options.placement,
        'title': options.title,
        'trigger': options.trigger
    }).on({
        'blur': function() {
        console.log('ON BLUR EVENT'); // this is getting executed 2x.
        $('#' + $element.id).tooltip('show');
        }
    });
```

My params are coming in correctly, my messages are all correct when I log everything out. Just not sure how to get around the blur event getting executed twice.

I've also tried using `focusout` but no luck.

Comment: can you create a bootply.com demonstrating your issue?

Comment: Yep. I was working on a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damonjentree/7gTu4/6/)
If you click in the input, then leave it - all good. Do it again, and the blur gets executed twice. (check the console logs)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching a blur event handler every time you call your `initTooltip` function so on blur they will be fired all.

You can eventually reconsider your code or move from jQuery `on` to jQuery [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element per event type.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Usk3P/

Comment: I should have taken a walk and come back with a fresh set of eyes. I can see exactly what you are talking about. Thank you very much for your help!